# Вопрос удален во время ответа. Это баг или такое бывает?

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, ответы, удаление-вопросов

Пока я набирал текст для ответа на [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/475349), появилось уведомление о том, что вопрос удален.
Кнопка отправки заблокировалась. Я закрыл страницу.
Но оказалось, что вопрос на месте и ответы есть и комментарии от других участников.

[image: скриншот страницы]

Если это не баг, то из-за такой особенности, как мне кажется, возможны хитрые злоупотребления, по получению баллов.
Но тут надо внимательно смотреть на даты регистрации тех, кто спрашивает, время прошедшее до удаления вопроса и т.д.
Хотя, возможно, это просто предновогодняя паранойя :)

UPDATE:

Почти такая же ситуация произошла еще с один [вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/475383).  Вопрос удалили, пока отвечал.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Наверное, день был просто неудачный.

Comment: это как-то неправильно. хорошо что ответ был не большой. иначе было бы жаль потраченного времени. наверное надо сообщать автору вопроса, что кто-то пишет ответ. и не удалять, а ставить в очередь на удаление, и если ответ не будет опубликован, то только тогда удалить.

Comment: Хм. Какие гламурные плашки.

Comment: @Stack, ну, всех исходов событий тут не предусмотришь. Да и хорошо, что вопрос можно быстро удалять. По многим причинам.

Comment: @Stack В нормальных условиях ваше сообщение сохраняется (вероятно, в LocalStorage), поэтому ничего потеряться не должно. То есть или ваше сообщение не успело сохраниться, или было удалено вместе с вопросом — пока неясно. Так или иначе, это очень редкий случай.

Comment: А вместо <br/> можно ставить два пробела перед переводом строки.

Comment: Дайте теме нормальное название

Comment: br убрал, спасибо. Название темы поменял. Про редкий случай дописал в текст вопроса.

Comment: @Discord _"Так или иначе, это очень редкий случай"_ -- два раза за сегодня.

Comment: Второго инцидента можно было избежать следующим образом: не отвечать на вопросы не по теме сайта.

Comment: @NormalHuman _"не отвечать на вопросы не по теме сайта."_ -- на сайте я всего 5 дней и не совсем понимаю, почему этот вопрос - не по теме, а аналогичные, на мой взгляд, вопросы оставлены - [этот](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431135) и [этот](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/192766).

Answer (score 7):

Если посмотреть [историю изменений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/475349/revisions), то можно заметить, что вопрос был удалён и буквально через минуту восстановлен автором вопроса.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какой колеблющийся автор.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, свои возможности тестировал видимо.