# Задавать вопросы и самому на них отвечать - это уже не приветствуется на ruSO?

Tags: обсуждение

Если я сам задаю вопрос и сам на него отвечаю - это уже не приветствуется на ruSO?
Вопрос этот возник из-за ситуации с моим [вопросом-ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480924).
Мне там настойчиво предлагают решение, которое не подходит и *"срабатывает в 99% случаев"*. А когда я уточнил вопрос, то меня чуть ли не в подтасовке обвиняют, говорят: *"Поменять вопрос так, чтобы ваш ответ стал ему соответствовать лучше, чем другой? Мда."*.
Странная ситуация, особенно если посмотреть на автора *"Мда"* и несколько минусов (сговорились что-ли?).
@NicolasChabanovsky обратите, пожалуйста, внимание.

---

В своем ответе я предложил использовать ProcessCmdKey и получил несколько минусов и странное обсуждение. А такое же решение [на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386695/disadvantage-of-setting-form-keypreview-true) - 46 плюсов. Почему мне поставили минусы?

---

Почему я решил заострить внимание на ситуации? Потому что уже [была дискуссия](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33519/discussion-between-pashapash-and-stack), но в тот раз был только [минус](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/478676), и обошлось без обвинений в мой адрес.

---

PashaPash♦: *"Я сделал вполне логичный вывод - суть правки - заставить лично меня удалить мой ответ. Не улучшить сайт, не прояснить проблему, а просто подставить меня как участника, и заодно заставить меня выбросить в урну пост, на оформление которого я потратил силы и время. Подобные исправления вопросов, на мой взгляд, неприемлемы.

Поставил минус и оставил негодующий комментарий. Получил волну возмущения."*

Отвечаю: если мое дополнение (именно дополнение) "подставило вас", то что сказать о ситуации: ["Вопрос удален во время ответа."](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2081). Вопрос был удален, когда я написал ответ. Через какое-то время оказалось, что вопрос восстановили и ответ @PashaPash оказался зеленым с +1. И что мне теперь думать? Надо поставить минус и оставить "негодующие комментарии"? :)

А возмущение мое из-за того, что вы сказали *"Поменять вопрос так, чтобы ваш ответ стал ему соответствовать лучше, чем другой? Мда."*. Прошу воздержаться от подобных обвинений.

Comment: Если вопрос действительно отредактирован после появления ответа на него, это не очень хорошо. С другой стороны, если в альтернативном ответе предлагается решение, которое не всегда работает, имеет смысл указать на это в комментариях к ответу.

Comment: И насколько я понимаю, хорошие вопросоответы приветствуются как и раньше.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34175/discussion-on-question-by-stack--------).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В вопросе (на Мете) вы поднимаете два обсуждения:

1. Приветствуется ли задавать вопросы и отвечать на них.
2. Что делать в конкретно этом случае.

---

**Приветствуется ли задавать вопросы и отвечать на них**

Да, конечно же приветствуется! Ответы на свои вопросы – это один из способов поделиться знаниями с сообществом. Более того, именно основываясь на ответах на свои вопросы сайт был в принципе запущен. Подобный способ систематизации знаний позволяет не только собрать набор заметок с прикладными решениями задач, но и получить отзыв сообщества о самих решениях. Далеко не все решения, которые мы знаем оптимальны...

**Что делать в конкретно этом случае**

Stack Overflow – это открытое место, где каждый желающий может дополнить существующий ответ или предложить свой. Вопросы с ответами себе – не исключение. Если другой участник видит, что решение можно улучшить, либо что существует альтернативная точка зрения, он в праве опубликовать новый ответ. Если кого-то чем–то не устраивает ответ автора вопроса, ничего не может остановить участника от голосования против. И это здорово! Именно в этом и есть ценность проверки решений сообществом.

Если автор любого вопроса считает, что не до конца ясно изложил проблему, он волен внести уточняющие изменения в вопрос, с условием, что это останется тот же вопрос (за этим и нужна правка). Если после этого, часть ответов стала неверна – к сожалению, такова жизнь. Если автор ответа, который стал нерелевантным, считает, что знания могут быть полезны сообществу, он может удалить ответ в текущем (исправленном) вопросе и задать новый, для которого ответ будет верным. Как мне кажется, это один из оптимальных способов разрешения ситуации.

---

**Обновление**

Вариант с удалением ответа, ставшим нерелевантным после обновления вопроса – лишь один из способов выхода из *неоднозначной ситуации*.

Другим отличным решением может быть перенос в ответ автора вопроса всех внесенных дополнений в вопрос. Таким образом ответы других участников будут соответствовать вопросу, а ответ автора вопроса будет более точен в контексте заданных условий.

Comment: Думаю, автор такого вопроса должен быть готов к тому, что его же ответ на этот вопрос может быть **не самым правильным**. Особо не обращал внимания на такие ситуации, но они бывают, например : [вчерашняя ситуация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/481194/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-stdadvance-next-prev) (наверняка - тоже неожиданная для автора, он ведь тоже старался над своим ответом).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34174/discussion-on-answer-by-nicolas-chabanovsky-------).

Comment: *"Если после этого, часть ответов стала неверна – к сожалению, такова жизнь."* -- не следует вносить  правки в вопросы, которые делает неверными текущие ответы (я просто откатываю такие правки сразу). Задайте новый вопрос вместо этого.

Answer (score 8):

Взгляд на ситуацию с моей точки зрения (как второго участника войны ответов):

- Я увидел базовый вопрос по использованию технологии, запощенный как вопрос/ответ.
- Приведённое решение показалось мне не самым простым/лучшим/общепринятым.
- Я не стал устаивать драму в комментах к чужим ответам.
- Я написал свой ответ, подкрепив его ссылками на гайдлайны и стандартные howto по технологии.
- Получил уточняющий комментарий. Дополнил ответ.
- В ответ на это получил правку *вопроса*, которая превратила вопрос из базового вопроса по технологии в специфический кейс (диалоговые окна, на winforms, без единой кнопки). И, соответственно, сделало собственный ответ топикастера единственным применимым. Это в чистом виде подгонка под ответ.
- Правка вопроса делает мой ответ полностью неприменимым. Технически, я вынужден его теперь удалить - он не решает проблему, описанную в вопросе.
- Я сделал вполне логичный вывод - суть правки - заставить лично меня удалить мой ответ. Не улучшить сайт, не прояснить проблему, а просто подставить меня как участника, и заодно заставить меня выбросить в урну пост, на оформление которого я потратил силы и время. Подобные исправления вопросов, на мой взгляд, неприемлемы.
- Поставил минус и оставил негодующий комментарий. Получил волну возмущения.

Несмотря на ромб, у меня все есть право отвечать, минусовать и комментировать. И не перед кем не отчитываться, по крайней мере по первым двум действиям. Это пост - исключение.

На мой взгляд, правка значительно ухудшила вопрос. Настолько, что будь он задан как обычный вопрос, его сразу бы закрыли и заминусовали. То, что решение к нему скопировано из совершенно другого (не переведенного, а просто другого) вопроса с enSO - не делает вопрос лучше.

---

Ваш вопрос - не перевод и не копия вопроса на enSO. Это проявление [Ошибки XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/). На английском написано "у меня проблема Y, вот решение для Y". На русском вы написали "у меня проблема X, есть решение для Y". И настаиваете на том, что Y - единственное решение для X.

---

Минусы в тот раз поставил вам не я. Ищите врага в другом месте. Я поставил два плюса. Если вам это не нравится - могу убрать.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34173/discussion-on-answer-by-pashapash--------).

Comment: Хочу напомнить, что вы тоже можете задать вопрос и перенести туда свой ответ.

Answer (score 8):

Для случая, когда у диалога есть кнопка отмены, тот ответ явно лучше. Хотя бы из-за того, что не придётся дублировать логику обработки отмены. Да и вообще, нет смысла перехватывать клавишу, когда есть стандартный механизм. Так что отсутствие этого способа явно является недостатком твоего ответа.

По поводу того, что надо сделать. Во-первых, перенести информацию об отсутствии кнопок из вопроса в свой ответ. Написать что-то типа "Как правило можно воспользоваться свойством CancelButton, однако, иногда встречаются диалоги без кнопок, как, например, ...". После этого оба ответа станут корректными и оба нельзя будет упрекнуть в существенных недостатках. После этого мне кажется логичным принять ответ PashaPash, как более частоиспользуемый.

PS: Минусов не ставил.

PPS: Я вот [тоже думаю](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/479324/178988), какой ответ принять. Склоняюсь к тому, что Майка.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34176/discussion-on-answer-by-qwertiy--------).