# Аккумуляция знаний на SO самоответами

Tags: обсуждение, самоответы

Можно ли SO использовать как базу для сохранения своих, не знаю, как это точно назвать, знаний или заметок? Например, я нахожу определенную задачу или проблему, решаю ее, а затем оформляю ее условие (формулировку) в виде вопроса и сразу же публикую самоответ.

Я прочитал соответствующие посты на мете о возможности дополнительного вознаграждения за самоответ, организаю SO как «город знаний» и т.п. Но здесь я не преследую цель получить вознаграждение, а скорее использовать SO как хранилище каких-то вещей, которые я где-то прочитал, увидел и хочу сохранить, чтобы позже повторить, вспомнить и применить где-то.

**Почему SO?**

1. Удобно будет искать соответствующую проблему/задачу/алгоритм и т.п. в своей базе.
2. Адекватное форматирование - выделение кода, цитирования, гиперссылок.
3. Какие альтернативы - блокнот, LaTeX, от руки или память - так себе.
4. Возможно, эти знания помогут другим страждущим и ищущим.

Собственно, мои сомнения в том, что не будут ли мои действия расценены отрицательно сообществом? Например, некоторые вопросы, даже если и будут аккуратно и понятно оформлены, будут представлять интерес для очень небольшой группы участников, а минимально - только для меня самого. Может, кто-то найдет что-то полезное и для себя.

Хотя я рад комментариям по делу других участников по моим вопросам с самоответами.

Comment: [self-answer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Хм, вроде на мете был ответ про самоответы, но что-то не смог найти :(

Comment: Что-то я вспомнил одного участника, который начинал с кучи вопросов с самоответами..... потом такаааааааая драма была, такая драаммма))

Comment: Если публиковать самоответ, он должен быть качественным (как вопрос, так и ответ). А то может получиться как тут: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2286/Задавать-вопросы-и-самому-на-них-отвечать-это-уже-не-приветствуется-на-ruso

Comment: @VadimTagil буду изменять только разве что внешний вид и оформление вопроса, никаких дополнений или качественных изменений, влияющих на смысл вопроса.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Никаких особых правил в отношении материала, публикуемого таким образом, нет.**

Так что всё будет происходить, как обычно. Некоторые, может, даже не заметят, что авторы вопроса и ответа на самом деле одно лицо.

---

- хорошие вопросы заплюсуют
- плохие вопросы заминусуют
- оффтопик и неконкретику закроют и, возможно, удалят

  - встречал несколько случаев с самоответами, когда участник задавал широченный вопрос и давал на него ответ, который для своего вопроса на полноту даже близко не претендует; такие вопросы закрывались, ответы минусовались
- дубликаты задубликатят (но могут, несмотря на это, заплюсовать, [случай](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/676514/181100))
- попытки *совсем уж наглой* рекламы собственных продуктов сожгут на месте как спам

  - даже в формате публикации ответов о них
  - это не отменяет того, что сообщения, несущие реальную пользу сколько-нибудь существенной группе лиц, одобряются; даже если от них немножко отдаёт рекламой
  - у нас в справке [отдельная страница есть на смежную тему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/product-support)

---

- хорошие ответы, соответственно, заплюсуют
- однобокие или по иным причинам плохие ответы заминусуют

  - как обычно, то, что решение помогло автору, ещё не значит, что оно хорошее
- голые (без непосредственного материала) ссылки и сборники ссылок удалят

  - а возможно вдобавок и заминусуют
- плагиат не приветствуется

---

<sub>Также релевантно: [Изменение вопроса - подмена или дополнение?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2299/181100)</sub>

Answer (score 9):

Если вопросы будут в пределах [тематики](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), то все будут только за. Если вопросы и ответы к ним будут интересны/полезны, то и репутации накапает.

Comment: Вопрос для уточнения: самоответ можно принять только через 48 часов, насколько я знаю, и баллы 15 репутации не начисляются. Есть еще какие-то «организационные» отличия самоответа от обычного ответа?

Comment: @Jenssen [другой ответ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6302/23044) более реалистичным является (либо не обратят внимание что вы автор и минусы за узкость охвата или обратят и минусы за [мнимую] погоню за репутацией поставят. Будьте уверены, что у вас материалы ещё где-то продублированы так как вопрос может быть закрыт и удалён. [Пример](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43948164/4279)

Answer (score 4):

В целом, идея отличная. Важны детали.

Формат SO предполагает конкретные, «атомарные» задачи, изложенные в стиле «проблема — решение». Если сомневаетесь

- Почитайте  [заплюсованные самоответы](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/759943/best-self-answered-questions) .
- Обратитесь за ревью к опытным участникам. Например, положите текст в Google Docs, создайте ссылку с правом комментирования и опубликуйте эту ссылку в чате. Попросите, чтобы текст прочитали и дали вам обратную связь.

Я как-то делал такое ревью для очень хорошего самоответа. Вроде какую-то пользу автору принёс. Если воспользуетесь моим советом — пинганите меня в чате (через `@nickvolynkin`), обещаю прочитать и откомментировать.

Comment: Зачем такие сложности с гуглдоками? Ревью можно и прямо на этом сайте делать...

Comment: @PavelMayorov в гуглдоке можно комментировать строки и предлагать правки, а тут можно только взять и отредактировать.

Comment: @PavelMayorov то есть для качества контента- нормально, а для обучения автора - нет.