# Как поделиться интересным решением?

Tags: обсуждение

Нашел на просторах интернета интересное и, на мой взгляд, полезное для сообщества решение моей задачи. Хочется поделиться им с пользователями СО. Как это лучше сделать? Задать вопрос и самому на него ответить с решением проблемы?

Comment: _Задать вопрос и самому на него ответить с решением проблемы_.

Comment: Кстати, можно сделать это уже и на текущей странице :)

Comment: И ещё раздел справки: [Можно ли ответить на свой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Если вы сомневаетесь, что хорошо выбрали формат и масштаб вопроса — 1) почитайте [заплюсованные самоответы](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/759943/best-self-answered-questions) и 2) [предложите ваш вопрос и ответ на ревью перед публикацией](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6306/181472)