# Не вопрос на SO

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, вопросы

**Здравствуйте!** Допустимо ли ruSO задать вопрос (который на самом деле вопросом не является), и создан исключительно для того, чтобы участники могли:

- Продемонстрировать навыки владения какой-либо тулзой
- Продемонстрировать интересные фичи
- Показать, как что-либо сделать что-нибудь интересное из мира IT и programming
- Ну, и просто показать что-либо интересное, что по мнению участника будет интересно другим участникам

Все 4 пункта относятся к какой-либо теме, которой будет назначен какой-либо тэг, который будет создан (разумеется).

**Добавлю один момент: это не аккумуляция знаний, а способ что-либо продемонстрировать по какой-либо теме (скорее, узконаправленной).**

В общем, в данном контексте - это будет не вопрос, и все так называемые ответы - по факту ответами являться не будут, а будут просто демонстрировать что-либо по определенной теме. (Ну я потом придумаю, как оформлять, чтобы было красиво, и четко). Насколько я понял, участник может дать не 1 ответ, а несколько. (Сколько - пока не знаю, еще не уточнял).

Поэтому, считаю, что данное предложение имеет место быть. Или это идет вразрез с правилами сообщества?

Вопросы? Дополнения? Пожелания? Спрашивайте!

---

Update: `PashaPash` попросил меня привести немного конкретики. Привожу:

Например, у нас есть главный "вопрос" с тэгом `#rusotest` (пусть пока такое имя будет), в нём будут изложены правила, общая информация об этой затее, ну и что нового появилось на просторах ruSO c тэгом `#rusotest-ключевое_слово`. Предположим, я, беру и создаю "вопрос". Пишу название **Perl one-liners**, указываю там тэг `#rusotest-perl-one-liners`, и вот, всё, готово!

Теперь все участники могут показать какие-нибудь крутые штуки по этой теме*.

*Подразумевается:

- Продемонстрировать навыки владения какой-либо тулзой
- Продемонстрировать интересные фичи
- Показать, как что-либо сделать что-нибудь интересное из мира IT и programming
- Ну, и просто показать что-либо интересное, что по мнению участника будет интересно другим участникам

Comment: Может быть добавите немного конкретики и приедете пример вопроса?

Comment: @PashaPash https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78973/so-without-q - присоединяйтесь! Добавлю конкретики!

Comment: Краткосрочная польза понятна, а в чём долгосрочная? Чем подобные ответы могут помочь читателям?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Специфика Stack Overflow подразумевает в той или иной мере, что наполнение сайта происходит по схеме «вопрос-ответ». То есть, это даже не «тема», как обычно принято на сайтах формата форума, которая может довольно сильно раздуваться. Тут любят конкретику. Попытка собрать «винегрет» на одной странице, пусть и относящийся к какой-то конкретной метке, будет воспринят как «слишком общий вопрос», подлежащий последующему закрытию.

Если хочется собрать какие-то интересные фичи, продемонстрировать навыки и т.д. из списка, озвученного в вопросе, то всё что для этого нужно, чтобы оставаться в формате SO, это — придерживаться схемы «вопрос-ответ», см. [как задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) и выбирать подходящие метки для группировки таких вопросов.

Приведу упрощенные примеры по первому пункту из предложения:

> Продемонстрировать навыки владения какой-либо тулзой

- Как сохранить файл в «блокноте»?
- Как отправить на печать только первую страницу?
- Как изменить кодировку файла?

Все эти вопросы довольно конкретны, но связаны единой темой «блокнот», это и будет общая для них метка. Размещать всё это на одной странице под заголовком наподобие «Руководство по работе с блокнотом» не стоит. Люди приходят на SO за решением конкретных проблем, для ознакомления «в общем» существует документация на тулзу. А если, тем не менее, хочется узнать по максимуму из того, что есть на SO — достаточно просто вывести список вопросов по интересующей метке.

Если хочется поделиться знаниями — на сайте вполне приветствуется схема [вопросов с само-ответами](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6300/176217).

Comment: Я вас понял. Спасибо!

Comment: Пример лучше заменить с блокнота на какую-нибудь абстрактную IDE: у нас и так достаточно часто люди не понимают разницы между вопросами, которые возникают у пользователей программы и вопросами, которые относятся к программированию.

Comment: @AK а чем "блокнот" не IDE? :) Я не думаю, что непрограммист, увидев моё сообщение здесь, примет решение, что можно теперь позадавать вопросы о блокноте, выходящие за онтопичность сайта. Очень маловероятное событие, кмк.

Answer (score -3):

Да, можно, но если оно подходит под метку [соревнование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5).
Подробнее в [соответствующем вопросе](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2933/178988) и описании метки.

Comment: Дело в том, что это не соревнование!

Comment: @misdeed, ну можно немного подпилить что-нибудь, чтобы стало соревнованием?

Comment: В чем соревноваться будем? Ведь ни вопроса, ни задания - нет...